# what is effective index method which is used to solve modes in rectangular waveguide?

Tags: optics, research-level, fiber-optics, waveguide

I actually want to know the basics of effective index methods for solving the optical modes in slab/rectangular waveguides.

Answer (score 1):

The effective index method is an analytical method applicable to complicated waveguides such as ridge waveguides and diffused waveguides.

The ridge waveguide, such as shown in Figure Below, is difficult to analyze with simple method since the waveguide structure is too complicated to deal with by the division of waveguide. In order to analyze ridge waveguides, you should use numerical methods, such as the finite element method and finite difference method.

[image]

The wave equation for $E_x$ is given by:
$$\frac{\partial^2H_y}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 H_y}{\partial y^2}+[k^2n^2(x, y)-\beta^2]H_y=0$$

**The basic assumption of the effective index method is that the electromagnetic field can be expressed, with the separation of variables, as:**
$$H_y(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$$

Substituting this above and divided by XY
$$\frac{1}{X}\frac{d^2 X}{dx^2}+\frac{1}{Y}\frac{d^2 Y}{dy^2}+[k^2n^2(x, y)-\beta^2]=0$$
Here we add to and subtract from the equation above the independent value of $k^2n_{eff}^2$
and separate the equation into two independent equations:
$$\frac{1}{Y}\frac{d^2 Y}{dy^2}+[k^2n^2(x, y)-k^2n_{eff}^2(x)=0$$$$\frac{1}{X}\frac{d^2X}{dx^2}+[k^2n_{eff}^2(x)-\beta^2]=0$$

Now we have two equation with one variable that can be applied to x and y boundary and in this way discontinuity of refractive index can be treated simpler.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Note that we have an [equation editor built into the site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) which helps for readability of your post.

Comment: Don't post formulae as pictures or plain text, but use MathJax instead. MathJax is easy for people on all devices to read, and can show up clearer on different screen sizes and resolutions. I've edited it here as an example. Look at [this Math SE meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) for a quick tutorial.

Comment: I think you want to write $H_y$ and not $E_x$ in the first sentence below the figure "The wave equation for $E_x$ is given by: "

Comment: I am not comfortable with the part where you seperate the equation into two independent equations. The two equations could be true, but don't have to be necessarily true, right? They could, as easily, be equal and opposite, right?

Comment: I believe the above answer is directly copied from Page 38 of the book 'Fundamentals of optical waveguides', but without a proper acknowledgement.